# Geometric meaning behind discriminant of multivariate polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm taking an algebra course in Galois Theory and we have now gone over the algebraic/combinatoric meaning of the discrimiannt of a polynomial $P(x) = \Sigma a_i x^i$ as:

$\Delta_P=\begin{equation*}
  \prod_{i<j} (r_i-r_j)^2
\end{equation*}a^{2n-2}$ where $r_i$ denotes a root of $P(x)$. This is a really neat algebraic formula but I can't help but wonder what's hiding behind it. I'm sure there is some deeper intuition to the discriminant besides *knowing if a polynomial has real roots*, mainly geometric interpretation hiding behind it, and its generalization to the multivariate polynomial case. Thanks!

Comment: Is $P$ really a multivariate polynomial?

Comment: Of course not, but I'm interested in generalizations of what was shown in class.

Comment: In that case it might help if you mention it explicitly in the text.